# How to start Main App from (Foreground Service) Notification?

Tags: android, delphi

My App starts an background Service and adds a Notification - all working fine except that i can't figure out how to launch my App when the user clicks the Notification...
(i need a correct JPendingIntent...)

Here is my Source for SetForground Procedure, called in OnStartCommand:

```
Procedure TDatasnapServiceModule.SetForeground(aTitle, aText: String; aNr: Integer);
    var service            : JService;
        serviceObjectId    : Pointer;
        ntf                : JNotification;
        intent             : JIntent;
        PendingIntent      : JPendingIntent;
    begin
      serviceObjectId := (JavaService as ILocalObject).GetObjectID;
      service         := TJService.Wrap(serviceObjectId);
      ntf             := TJNotification.Create;
      ntf.icon        := service.getApplicationInfo.icon;
      if aNr > 0 then
        ntf.Number    := aNr;
    // empty intent, works but App is not started/activated (of course...)
      intent  := TJIntent.Create;

    // what to put into this intent so my App launches when user clicks?

      PendingIntent := TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.getActivity(service.getApplicationContext, ServiceID, intent, 0);
      ntf.setLatestEventInfo(service.getApplicationContext, StrToJCharSequence(aTitle), StrToJCharSequence(aText), PendingIntent);
      service.startForeground(NotifyID, ntf);
    end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to paste my code here. There's too much to discuss it in detail. Hopefully you'll just see the bit you have been missing, or what you might need to change in your own code, so that I don't have to do that for you.

```
function TMainService.AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject;
  const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
var
  ExtraData: String;
{$ifdef FOREGROUND}
  NewIntent: JIntent;
  ncb: JNotificationCompat_Builder;
  ntf: JNotification;
  PendingIntent: JPendingIntent;
{$endif}
begin

  // called EVERY TIME the service starts or automatically restarts
  LogMe('Startservice called');

  // Using NOT STICKY so the service gets automatically closed when the host closes
  // not need to try stopservice anymore :-)
  Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_NOT_STICKY;

  {$ifdef FOREGROUND}
    {$ifdef ORDINARY_NOTIFICATION}
    // unclickable
    PendingIntent := TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.getActivity(
      JavaService.getApplicationContext, 0, Intent, 0
      );
    ntf := TJNotification.Create;
    ntf.icon := JavaService.getApplicationInfo.icon;
    ntf.setLatestEventInfo(
      JavaService.getApplicationContext,
      StrToJCharSequence('Tracker Service'),
      StrToJCharSequence('Communications Service'), PendingIntent);
    {$else}
    // ALL THIS code is to make the host come to foreground when the user taps
    // the permanent notification
    // thanks to:
    // https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=847227
    // https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/6211176

    NewIntent:= TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
      TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageName());
    NewIntent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_MAIN);
    NewIntent.addCategory(TJIntent.JavaClass.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    NewIntent.addFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent := TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.getActivity(
      TAndroidHelper.Context, 0, NewIntent,
      TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
      );

    ncb := TJNotificationCompat_Builder.JavaClass.init(TAndroidHelper.Context);
    ncb.setContentTitle(StrToJCharSequence('GroupTracker Service'));
    ncb.setTicker(StrToJCharSequence('Communications Service'));
    ncb.setSmallIcon(JavaService.getApplicationInfo.icon);
    ncb.setContentIntent(PendingIntent);
    ncb.setOngoing(True);
    ntf := ncb.build;
    {$endif}
    LogMe('Start foreground called');
    JavaService.startForeground(StartId, ntf);
  {$endif}

  {$ifdef STOPSELF}
  LogMe('stopSelf');
  // this actually queues the stop request until the host stops running
  // almost like START_NOT_STICKY really
  JavaService.stopSelf(StartId);
  // using unbind and stop instead, thanks
  {$endif}

  if Intent <> nil then
  begin
    ExtraData := TAndroidHelper.JStringToString(
      Intent.getStringExtra(TAndroidHelper.StringToJString('ExtraData')));
    LogMe('ExtraData=' + Extradata);
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Thanks nolaspeaker - that solved my problem!  It was the part with the JNotificationCompat_Builder that i was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Create foreground notification and add pendingIntent

```
  fun createForegroundNotification(account: Account): Notification {
    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, ID)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setContentIntent(createMainActivityIntent())
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
            .setWhen(0)
            .setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
    return notification.build()
}
```

Content intent code

```
   private fun createMainActivityIntent(): PendingIntent {
    val intent = Intent(mContext, MainActivity::class.java)
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jarvis, i will have a closer look at the JNotificationCompat_Builder

Comment: @Jarvis. Notice this is a Delphi question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for get main class:

```
private static Class getMainActivityClass(Context context) {
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    Intent launchIntent = 
         context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    String className = launchIntent.getComponent().getClassName();
    try {
        return Class.forName(className);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And use this class in for this pendingIntent :

```
int yourRequestCode  = 66 ;
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, getMainActivityClass(this));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this,yourRequestCode, 
                 resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And finally use this pending intent in

> .setContentIntent

of your notification.